# ASP.NET Intranet and Internet website

Tags: asp.net

I am designing ASP.NET website for Intranet users. At the end of Phase-I this will be available to Intranet users.

But after Phase-II, the same site needs to be opened to certain users that are outside this office.

Can I can use ASP.NET Membership provider?

Any other design recommendations?

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do.

- I would use ASP.net MembershipProvider and use SQL server to store it.
- Create roles (internal user and external user)
- I would use high encryption for passwords for all users
- user roles to limit the information external users can see

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the ASP.Net membership provider to allow external users to register and login to the site. Using this would ensure that the passwords are hashed with a salt and encrypted, thus making the user data more secure. The ASP.Net membership provider has a huge API set which might be confusing for developers, among other things. There is a simplified membership provider which is available in the WebMatrix suite called SimpleMembershipProvider, which is available in the  WebMatrix.WebData namespace. This gives just enough API needed to create, manage, authenticate and authorize external users.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "outside this office". You can use the ASP.NET membership classes with any sort of provider that may suite your needs. Do you mean by intranet users, that you want the users to be able to sign in to your web site with their windows domain account?

Generally you can use the `SqlMembershipProvider` to authenticate users against a SQL Server dabase with a given set of tables using the ASP.NET login controls. If you want to use the login controls and but want users to be able to login using their windows account you can use the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`. If none of the above is suitable for you, there's always the option to implement a custom provider.

Comment: outside this office - different location and users dont have domain access. From your answer I am understanding that we will using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider for intranet users and SqlMembershipProvider for external users. Thank you!